# Fetch and replace content dynamically from API with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a Web App that is refreshing every 5 seconds (meta tag HTML) and connects to a web service everytime I refresh the page to show the JSON results. But now I need this to happen just when there is a new value on the JSON (like a socket), is there any way to keep XMLHttpRequest "listening" from the API reloading the page if there is anything new?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want something like a socket if sockets are already invented?

Comment: Good question, I just can't figure out how to work with sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way to do this would be to do the following using a webSocket:

1. Don't refresh your web page with meta tag
2. When your page is first loaded in the browser, make a webSocket connection to your server.  This will be a continuous connection.
3. In the client set up a listener for various messages that your server can send.
4. On the server when something of interest to the client changes, then send a message to the client.
5. When the client receives a message of interest, it can then dynamically modify the current page to show that change (no need to reload the page).

FYI, socket.io is a library built on top of webSockets that offers additional useful functionality (such as auto-reconnect and message passing).